# Is it possible when you call a class it returns a variable in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables

I'm looking to replace a variable in my program with a class object. However, I'd like to avoid changing the syntax in my code. Let's say we have a class that looks like:

```py
class newClass():
    x=1
```

is it possible to setup a funcion within the class that when I setup the object `x_value` using:

```py
x_value = newClass()
```

Then when I call `x_value` it won't return:

```py
<__main__.newClass at 0x7fbe87284550>
```

but will return:

```
1
```

I looked into some of the special methods like `__str__`, but it seems it will only work when it's called within a print function. Or `__call__` which requires me to call `x_value` as `x_value()` then I would be able to return what ever I want, but this would require me to change quite a lot of code.

Comment: Why do you want to replace a variable by a class if you want it to behave like a variable throughout the rest of your code? If it should always return a value, it cannot be used as a class (you can't call methods on it).

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What do you **really** want to do? Do you want to use ``newClass.x`` (a class attribute)? Or talking about ``call``, do you want a class method, that returns a value w/o creating an instance? Maybe you want to use an ``Enum``?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "call" x_value? Do you mean print? Do you mean doing operations with it?

Comment: "__call__" x_value? Do you mean initialize? or do you mean call like a method in the class? Your question is unclear.

Comment: Maybe you just want a function that returns 1? Or else a `__new__` method that returns 1?

Comment: maybe you're looking for the `__repr__` method. Just return the value you want to be shown in it.

Comment: Most of the code I want to use `x_value` that returns the `x` value. However, it would be nice to attach some meta data at some point in my code. Using `x_value.metadata = {'some':'dict'}`, then this object will be passed around with this meta data. While in most cases it will just always get `x` when called. This will allow me to sort of inject some data at one point while using it somewhere else. In all honesty it should have been a class when we designed the code.

Comment: You *can* have a class that doesn't return an object of it's type when called, by overriding `__new__`, but what would be the point? `x _value = MyClass()` returns a regular `int`, that won't carry around any meta information.

Comment: I think you are using the term "called" imprecisely. To *call* an object in Python means `some_object()`  i.e., *the parentheses*, like *calling a function*. Just doing `some_object` doesn't *call* anything. That is merely referencing a variable, which evaluates to whatever object variable is referring to. If you literally mean an `int`, maybe just subclass `int`?